# How to change debounce time on mouse

Tags: mouse, 21.10

I have a mouse J95 model and I wondered if I could change my debounce time, I heard that mice have a lot of problem in doing this on Linux, and the software is Windows only, so I wondered if there's some other way to do it except installing Windows on Virtualbox.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?